# Loop Users Role and validate if connected or not

Tags: php, wordpress

I am looping in the frontend to show all users of my wordpress site with a certain role.

The loop is working fine, but I need to validate each user if logged in or not in general, I have this code I adapted but it only changes the icon to my user if I am connected. it doesn't show the other logged in users.

Any help validating the connected user in the loop would be grateful.

Thanks
Rodrigo

```
<?php

/*
Template Name: Usuarios
*/

get_header(); ?>

<div class="cotainer">



      <?php 
        $args = array(
          'role' => 'Administrator',
          'fields' => 'all'
        );

        // The Query
        $user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

        // User Loop
        if ( ! empty( $user_query->get_results() ) ) {
          foreach ( $user_query->get_results() as $user ) {
            global $current_user;
            get_currentuserinfo(); ?>

            <!------ --------------------------------- >
            <div class="row"> <!--- Fila Por Usuario --->

              <div class="col-md-1">
              <?php 
              if ($current_user->ID == $user->ID) { ?>
                  <img src="" alt=""> <!--- Connected Icon --->
              <?php }
              else { ?>
                  <img src="" alt=""><!--- Disconnected Icon --->
              <?php } ?>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-5">
              <p> <?php echo $user->display_name; ?></p>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-6">
              <p> <?php echo $user->user_email; ?></p>
              </div>

            </div>

          <?php           }
        } else {
          echo 'No users found.';
        }

       ?>


</div>

<?php get_footer()?>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what your asking. Do you want to show all users that are currently logged in?

Comment: Hy @David.J thanks for writing, I wanna show them all, but the difference is thats theres an icon that changes if that user is logged in or logged out.